# Using samsung SSD magician on linux

Tags: linux, ssd, wine, samsung-magician

I have a samsung SSD and Samsung has a magician software for their SSD. I would like to use it, however I just have linux and the software is only supported on Windows. Is there a way to install it with wine? When I downloaded the installer and ran it with wine, I can only get past the first window which is where I select the language. After that, a window pops up that says, "INSTALLATION CANNOT CONTINUE: "Windows Management Instrumentation" service is disabled. Please enable and try again.

Is there any way I can run this software on linux? It may be helpful to know that I am running linux mint 15 xfce. I don't know what other info would be helpful. Please ask if more info is needed.

## Edit

I have solved this problem by obtaining [samsung magician DC](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/server_downloads.html), which runs natively on linux. [This](https://superuser.com/q/853247/249433) is my follow-up question about how to use Samsung Magician DC to update an SSD's firmware.

Comment: Would you like to use the whole application or some specific  functionality in the Samsung magician software?

Comment: I am not sure why I wanted this. I think I wanted to view smart information, but I have figured out a way to do that already. Another thing I wanted to do was update firmware, but now there is a way to do that in linux with magicianDC I think it is called. I tried to use [magicianDC](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/server_downloads.html) to update firmware, but I couldn't get it to work. I am too lazy to make the bootable usb through linux because you have to do some hacks to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and throw out the non-answer answer here.

I'm not sure any method of running the Windows SSD Magician is useful in Linux. That tool is primarily designed to tweak low level parameters of the Windows storage stack for optimal use of your SSD. While similar parameter tweaks are possibly useful under Linux, you're going to need to use a tool/script/commands specifically designed for Linux (and probably your particular distro).

Also, I would never suggest attempting to do a firmware update via WINE... sounds like a recipe for bricked hardware.

As for SMART monitoring, there are many native Linux tools for that.

Comment: I wanted it so I could update my firmware. I eventually found that samsung published a magician software that runs natively in linux. See my question [here](http://superuser.com/q/853247/249433) on how to use it.